# Как уменьшить нагрузку на базу данных?

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Занимаюсь разработкой и поддержкой движка на Laravel для сервиса  партнерских программ. Текущий трафик, который идёт на сервер порядка 30 миллионов посещений в сутки. К базе постоянно идёт ~1500 запросов в секунду. Это нормально и сервер с этим справляется отлично, но как только количество запросов возрастает до 6000 в секунду, сервер начинает откровенно подвисать.

В связи со сложившейся ситуацией возник вопрос, а как вообще можно разгрузить базу? СУБД MySQL, таблицы на InnoDB. Движок написан на Laravel.

Вообще количество запросов сократить не получается, т.к. фиксируется каждое посещение и посетитель закрепляется за партнёром. При этом все данные пишутся в БД, но сначала извлекаются и проверяются по некоторым параметрам.

Таблицы проиндексированы. Также используется CloudFlare.

Comment: Эм.. кэшировать? + реплики на других серверах для селектов

Comment: Мы не можем ответить на вопрос "как прооптимизировать нагрузку", если вы ничего не сообщаете о характере этой нагрузки. Можно только дать общие рекомендации типа "уменьшить количество джойнов" и "разнести разную нагрузку на разные сервера".

Comment: А что за сервер у вас ?  мне кажется что с 30 млн в сутки-- это надо переходить на дедик

Comment: Дедик, Dual Xeon X5650 / 32Gb RAM / 2x1TB 7.2K HDD + 128GB SSD

Comment: Сервер норм вроде, >  "но сначала извлекаются и проверяются по некоторым параметрам." Думаю в первую очередь вам надо попробовать логировать SELECT EXPLANT и посмотреть какой запрос в основном грузит. Пробовали использовать zend debugger?

Comment: Видимо часть нагрузки на БД надо переносить на какой нибудь кеш. memcached или что то другое, смотря что больше к задаче подходит. Что касается запросов, надо рассматривать каждый в отдельности и думать нельзя ли его как то оптимизировать, совместить с другими операциями

Comment: Как вариант: уменьшить трафик за счет архивирования текста запроса-к-серверу; Уменьшение длины запроса на 2-байта уже приведет к огромному снижению трафика в час

Answer (score 2):

В плане железа использовать горизонтальное или вертикальное масштабирование. Но в вашем случае конечно лучше использовать горизонтальное, в реализации сложнее - но потом проще масштабировать.

В плане кода:

- **Если у вас много JOIN в запросах.** Опишу на примере: Есть таблица    leads, и вспомогательные leads_attrs, leads_params, leads_times и т.д. Многие создают метод получения лидов сразу со всеми параметрами и далее используют его по всему проекту. Но можно пересмотреть все места использования и проверить, везде ли требуется подключение всех вспомогательных таблиц leads_attrs, leads_params, leads_times?
- **Количество выгружаемых данных по запросам.** Если есть к примеру таблица users, в которой присутствует 25 полей. Обычным
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 вы будете получать огромное количество
  данных. В таких местах требуется проверить, все ли данные требуются?
  Обычно требуется 3-5 параметров, остальные тянутся тяжелой ношей.
- **И самое главное кеширование.** В PHP фреймворках реализовано хорошее кеширование из коробки, его стоит использовать. Только в
  случае с кешированием главное не "переборщить". Требуется кешировать
  общие данные, которые чаще всего повторяются. Пример: на сайте есть
  таблица городов, которая каждый раз выгружается из базы, весь список
  городов лучше закешировать и каждый раз брать из кеша - нежели на
  каждой странице дёргать sql.